# How to display entity framework object as model with validation?

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, entity-framework-4.1

I have a populated object from using the entity framework.  Let's call it `Order`.  The order has different properties such as `Id`, `OrderDate`, `BillingAddress` and so on.  I need to let users update this data.

What's the best way to display this data in a form, while enforcing data annotations such as `[Required]`?  I see `MetadataType` mentioned a lot, but I haven't seen how I can connect the dots with displaying the data as well.

One approach that I *could* take, but I'd like to avoid because of redundancy, is creating my own model object that has nearly identical properties.  Then I would just need to basically just copy entity framework object A to new object B, where B has all my lovely data annotations.  It just seems like there might be a better way.

Could anyone provide me with an example of a good way to accomplish this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The "better way" is a big reason EF Code First is great.  Otherwise, the only other way to do what you need is to do a mapping.